# OpenCV expm() function

Tags: opencv, mat

OpenCV  has a `exp(inMat, outMat)` function that returns a matrix where each cell, (i,j) is `exp(inMat.at<>(i, j))`.

Is there a function that returns actually the exponent of a matrix (i.e., e^A)?

In MATLAB the function is `expm(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function, however, it is possible to decompose the matrix into eigenvalues and use the `exp(inMat, outMat)` function, namely,

[image]

```
void expm(const Mat& m0, Mat& m1)
{
    Mat eval, evec;
    cv::eigenNonSymmetric(m0, eval, evec);

    Mat eveci = evec.t().inv();
    Mat exp_eval;
    cv::exp(eval, exp_eval);
    m1 = evec.t() * Mat::diag(exp_eval) * eveci;
}
```

Usage example:

```
    double a[] = {0, 1, -3, 4};
    Mat m0(2, 2, CV_64FC1, a);
    Mat m1(2, 2, CV_64FC1);
    cout << "Matrix m0 : \n" << m0 << "\n";
    expm(m0, m1);
    cout << "Matrix m1 : \n" << m1 << "\n";
```